# Prove or disprove that there exists a number $u\geq 0$ such that $\lfloor u^n\rfloor -n$ is always even for all $n\geq 1$.

Tags: contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've been thinking about the following problem for almost a full day

> Prove or disprove that there exists a number $u\geq 0$ such that $\lfloor u^n\rfloor -n$ is always even for all $n\geq 1$.

This is from MIT's Putnam seminar series of problems.

I don't think that such a number should exist. However, I just cannot seem to prove it. Would someone like to venture a hint?

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted?

Comment: @GerryMyerson- How did you come up with $(3+\sqrt{17})/2$? Were you just looking for modifications to your previous solution that would have the required parity?

Comment: Actually, I found it on the web. Someone else had posed the problem, maybe it was on the Art of Problem Solving website, and that answer was given (but without the proof details I provided in the answer I posted here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New, improved solution.

Let $u=(3+\sqrt{17})/2$. We claim that for $n\ge1$ we have $\lfloor u^n\rfloor-n$ is even.

We note that $u$ and $\overline u=(3-\sqrt{17})/2$ are the roots of $x^2-3x-2$. 
Let $r_n=u^n+\overline u^n$. Then $r_0=2$, $r_1=3$, and $r_n=3r_{n-1}+2r_{n-2}\equiv r_{n-1}\bmod2$ for $n\ge2$, so $r_n$ is an odd integer for all $n\ge1$.

Note $-1<\overline u<0$

Let $s_n=\lfloor u^n\rfloor$. Then for $n$ odd we have $s_n=r_n$, and for $n$ even we have $s_n=r_n-1$. So, $s_n$ is odd for $n$ odd, and even for $n$ even, and we're done.

More generally, we could use $u=(a+b\sqrt c)/2$ with $a,b$ odd integers, $c\equiv1\bmod8$, $u>1$, $-1<(a-b\sqrt c)/2<0$.

This was question A-5 on the 1983 Putnam exam. The solution in the Monthly is very different, with less Number Theory, and more Analysis. I will copy out the first paragraph:

Inductively, we define a sequence of integers $3=a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ and associated intervals $I_n=[(a_n)^{1/n},(1+a_n)^{1/n})$ such that $a_n\ge3^n$, $a_n\equiv n\bmod2$, the sequence $\{(a_n)^{1/n}\}$ is nondecreasing, and $I_{n+1}\subseteq I_n$. When this has been done, $\{(a_n)^{1/n}\}$, being nondecreasing and bounded, will have a limit $u$ which is in $I_n$ for all $n$. Then $(a_n)^{1/n}\le u<(1+a_n)^{1/n}$ will imply $a_n\le u^n<1+a_n$ and so $\lfloor u^n\rfloor=a_n\equiv n\bmod2$ for all $n$.

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
Previous, not terribly helpful answer, retained for historical reasons:

Let $a,b,c$ be integers. Then $(a+b\sqrt c)^n+(a-b\sqrt c)^n$ is always an integer. Call it $r_n$.

Let $d$ be any integer dividng both $a$ and $bc$. Then $d$ divides $r_n$ for all $n$.

Now suppose further that $|a-b\sqrt c|<1$. Then $r_n$ is either $\lfloor(a+b\sqrt c)^n\rfloor$ or $\lfloor(a+b\sqrt c)^n\rfloor+1$, depending on whether $(a-b\sqrt c)^n$ is negative or positive.

This should give you all you need to construct an example. Try it!

Comment: Just confirming, you're saying that an example exists?

Comment: I'm giving you the tools you need, in order for you to decide.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have been puzzling over your hint for some time.  It follows quickly from the definition that $r_n$ is always even.  Let $u = a+b\sqrt c$.  If $a,b,c$ are chosen so that  $-1 < a-b\sqrt c < 0 $, for odd $n$ $\lfloor u^n \rfloor - n =r_n - n $, which is odd, and for even $n$, $\lfloor u^n \rfloor- n = r_n-1 -n $, which is again odd.  If instead we had chosen  $ 0 < a-b\sqrt c < 1 $ then $\lfloor u^n \rfloor - n $ alternates between even and odd.  I cannot find a $u$ this way that always results in an even answer.  What am I missing?

Comment: @WADon I think you're right.

Comment: @WADon- Do check the modified answer. I think it is correct